Cannot find external header included in a cmake built library
I have a very simple library with the following dtructure:
src
 - myLib.h
 - myLib.cpp
App
 - testApp.cpp
CMakelist.txt


cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Testing)


# JSON
find_package(nlohmann_json REQUIRED)


add_library(myLib SHARED
        src/myLib.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(myLib PUBLIC nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json)


set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE debug)


install(TARGETS myLib 
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
install(DIRECTORY src/ DESTINATION include FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h")

Building the library works fine but when I link with testApp.cpp, which just includes myLib.h, I get the following errors:
g++ testApp.cpp -o runApp -I ../install/include/ -l ../install/lib/libmyLib.so

./install/include/myLib.h:16:10: fatal error: nlohmann/json.hpp: No such file or directory
   16 | #include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

What could be going wrong here?

Libraries won't necessarily give you all of their headers when you link with them. In order to access headers externally, you need to define include directories.
Look into the commands, include_directories and target_include_directories on the CMake Docs in order to do this.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
